# go1.18 fuzzing doesn't instrument string comparison?

Tags: go

`go1.18beta1` fuzzer is unable to figure out "tomatos" is a crasher after almost 40M iterations. Is string comparison not instrumented in go1.18 beta or perhaps there is a flag that I am missing? I was able to write a very similar test case with dvyukov's go-fuzz and it crashes in about 25 fuzzing iterations.

```
func FuzzThing(f *testing.F) {
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, b []byte) {
        if len(b) < 6 {
            return
        }

        if string(b) == "tomatos" {
            t.Fatalf("error!")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: yes but typically fuzzers (libfuzzer, afl, go-fuzz) are able to figure out a certain keyword like "tomatos" without a corpus, because they are able to get an improving coverage signal since string comparison in the stdlib is instrumented at the basic-block level

Answer (score 1):

String comparison instrumentation isn't present:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50231